# AJAX tab container control is not visible on some client machines

Tags: ajax, tabcontainer

I have a simple asp.net application with an ajax tab container and other asp.net controls.
Some of the users can not see the tab container control, but when they copy and paste the page content, they can see it.

A user tried to display the page on two different machines with same internet explorer version(ver. 7.0.5730.13). He could display the tab container on one of the machine but on the other one , he couldn't.

Any ideas or any solutions on this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have compared IE security setting & other IE settings on these 2 given browsers.